# Multithreading with Apache DBCP

Tags: java, multithreading, connection-pooling, apache-commons-dbcp

My application  executes multiple queries in multiple threads.

Right now I am creating new connection for every query and I want to use pool to improve efficiency.

Can Apache DBCP pool work in multiple threads simultaneously, or it will "block" on some synchronized methods per every thread?

If it blocks, can I use something else?

**UPDATE**

In this article: [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/java.101/b10979/tips.htm#i1005436)  stated:

> Because all Oracle JDBC API methods are synchronized, if two threads
>   try to use the connection object simultaneously, then one will be
>   forced to wait until the other one finishes its use.

So I guess DBCP won't be able to deal with that?

I am also realizing that in this scenario  the pool won't help me, because each thread will ask for a connection and the thread will generate a new connection each time (until some of the threads ends and returns the connection to the pool)

Comment: To supplement the great answers below, the only time `getConnection()` may block is if you have no more `Connection`'s in your pool (ie: they are all currently executing transactions with your database).  But as soon as a transaction has completed, the `Connection` will be returned to your pool and the `getConnection()` will return a valid `Connection` instance.  Although all of this will depend on the configuration of your pool.

Answer (score 4):

A thread takes a connection from the pool and makes exclusive use of it until it is done, it doesn't share the connection with other threads. When it is done it returns the connection to the pool (usually the connection overrides the close method to return it to the pool). The benefit is that the connections don't have to be recreated for each use. But you shouldn't have multiple threads making simultaneous use of a database connection.

Comment: I wanted to avoid creating connection per thread to improve efficiency. Right now each thread creating it's own connection.

Comment: @user1658192 why not call getConnection() from DBCP data source instead sharing Connection instance?

Comment: what will happen when I call getConnection(), while same connection is already in use by other thread? Will the poll create a new connection?

Comment: @user1658192: sorry, what's the question? the point of having a pool is so no threads have to share connections with another thread.

Comment: @Nathan Hughes , the point of the pool is to avoid crating same connections for multiple threads.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Apache DBCP can work in multi-threads simultaneously. "block" happens when client code `getConnection()` to ensure correct behavior under race condition, for example, one `Connection` instance should not be got by two concurrent `getConnection()` requests. After that client code handles the `Connection` instances.

Concurrent scenario is major concern at server side pooling, such as popular Apache DBCP. So I think DBCP does well behavior in multi-thread, although I don't dive into the library deep.

And Apache DBCP just provides JDBC connection **pooling**, client code must use the `Connection` instances in correct multi-threads way which DBCP cannot guarantee.

Comment: I am not sure if I am right, but i think some of the methods of PreparedStatement that connection returns are synchronized. If so, connection will block per thread...

Comment: I don't find any methods in 'Connection' or 'Statement' is synchronized in JDBC.

Comment: So there is no problem using same connection in multiple threads, where each tread will execute different query?

Comment: No. 'getConnection' is thread safe operation which is guarrenteed by DBCP, but your code must ensure the Connection instance thread safe. For example, you borrow a book (Connection) from a library (DBCP), library ensures a book can be lent by one reader (your code), but afterwards, the book is handled by the reader who is responsible for the book handling.

Comment: I think I am not following you because if I do, this is not what I need. You are telling me that DBCP can only create one connection for user... But I need to share same connection between multiple users, so every one could execute query in parallel.

Comment: No, DBCP creates a pool of connections, the point being that when a thread needs to talk to the database it borrows a connection from the pool and returns it when it has finished.  There can be several parallel threads all talking to the database at the same time, each thread using a _different_ connection to do so.

Comment: OP is mixing logical connection (Connection object) with underlying socket conn. And DBCP handles that pretty fine, there's no blocking, as this answer states.

Comment: @Ian Roberts, in this case connection pool won't help me, because beside using pool I want to br able also to share single connection by multiple threads (with ability to execute query in parallel)